# Placeholder and Value Present at the Same Time

Tags: jquery, html

I have 6 digits number(for example: 123456), what I want is the input should appear something like this XXXX56. XXXX is placeholder while last two digits is the auto-populated value. So, when i key in first input should be like 1XXX56. Second key input should be like 12XX56. It is possible?

Comment: Tbh i don't think so,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```js
$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "999956"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="">  
  <div>
    <label for="phone">Mask</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need an input mask jQuery plugin, or similar.

This kind of thing: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask

The tricky bit might be the autopopulated value...