# Jquery Input Mask Plugin

Tags: jquery, html

How to populate the last two digits after the mask? Example: XXXX99 
So, when I key in the first digit should be 1XXX99

```js
var autoPopulateNo = "\\9\\9"  //how to put this after the mask? example XXXX99

$("#number").inputmask({
"mask": "9999" + autoPopulateNo,
clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
placeholder:"X",

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="">  
  <div>
    <label for="number">Mask</label>
    <input id="number" type="text"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome back, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44818443/placeholder-and-value-present-at-the-same-time/44818561#44818561

Comment: how about if the last two digits number is 99 instead of 56?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is so simple.You just append your variable with mask.

```js
var autoPopulateNo = 56  
$("#number").inputmask({
"mask": "9999"+autoPopulateNo,
clearMaskOnLostFocus: false,
placeholder:"X",

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
<form action="">  
  <div>
    <label for="number">Mask</label>
    <input id="number" type="text"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: could you try this? var autoPopulateNo = 99

Comment: I will check and tell.